# find out count of comma based value in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

```
Table Emp

    id   name
    1    Ajay
    2    Amol 
    3    Sanjay 
    4    Vijay

Table Sports

Sport_name     Played by
Cricket        ^2^,^3^,^4^
Football       ^1^,^3^ 
Vollyball      ^4^,^1^
```

Now I want to write a query which will give me output like

```
name   No_of_sports_played 
Ajay          2
Amol          1
Sanjay        2 
Vijay         2
```

So what will be Mysql query for this?

Comment: This calls for proper denormalization: For example, a separate `played_by` table that contains all the "played by" relationships

Comment: yes, but still there will be a way to find out count of sports played by employee....

Comment: '^' means a Concatenation Operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the above answers/comments that you are not using a database for what a database is for, but here is how you could calculate your table from your current structure in case you have no control over that:

```
SELECT Emp.name, IF(Played_by IS NULL,0,COUNT(*)) as Num_Sports
FROM Emp
LEFT JOIN Sports
ON Sports.Played_by RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',Emp.id,'[[:>:]]')
GROUP BY Emp.name;
```

See it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c91d4/9).
**UPDATE**: added the `IF(Played_by IS NULL,0,COUNT(*))` instead of `COUNT(*)`. This means that if an employee doesn't play anything they'll have a 0 as their `Num_Sports`. See it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff59f/4) (I also added in those `^` characters and it still works.

What it does is joins the Emp table to the Sports table if it can find the `Emp.id` in the corresponding `Played_by` column.

For example, if we wanted to see what sports Ajay played (id=1), we could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Emp, Sports
WHERE Sports.Played_by LIKE '%1%'
  AND Emp.id=1;
```

The query I gave as my solution is basically the query above, with a `GROUP BY Emp.name` to perform it for *each* employee.

The one modification is the use of [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) instead of `LIKE`.

I use `RLIKE '[[:<:]]employeeid[[:>:]]'` instead of `LIKE '%employeeid%`. The `[[:<:]]` symbols just mean "make sure the employeeid you match is a whole word".

This prevents (e.g.) `Emp.id` 1 matching the 1 in the `Played_by` of `3,4,11,2`.

Comment: ohh... I have just short doubt, as per ur link u didn't entered value like ^1^,^2^ in played by columns,, so is it works for that(^1^,^2^) format also?

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET()` works better than Regex, with comma-separated columns.

Comment: PravinGate - I really don't know what you mean by '^1^,^2^'. Do you mean the literal character '^'? In that case yes, it will work. @ypercube -- thanks! Didn't know about that function.

Comment: @PravinGate -- yes, it works with the `^` (see updated answer and link). If you have literal '^' then ypercube's suggestion of FIND_IN_SET won't work, but if there are no '^' then it will.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to store your relationships in a column like that. Create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE player_sports (player_id INTEGER NOT NULL, sport_id INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(player_id, sport_id));
```

This assumes you have an id column in your sports table. So now a player will have one record in player_sports for each sport they play.

Your final query will be:

```
SELECT p.name, COUNT(ps.player_id)
FROM players p, player_sports ps
WHERE ps.player_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.name;
```

Comment: sure this can be a way.  But most important my Played by
column in sports table has values in the format (^2^,^1^,^3^) then how we are going to calculate count ?

Comment: If you have no control over the DB then I could understand this issue, but if you do have control you really should change this method to a normalized method.

Comment: yes.... that's the thing I wanted to tell that I don't have control on db. and I need to find out a way by using query only..

Comment: ok, I understand that. Well, looks like the solution from @mathematical.coffee is your best bet.